# How to calculate and plot the joint distribution probability density function of independent variables

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Knowing that `X` and `Y` are independent of each other and follow the standard normal distribution, I want to know how to find and plot the probability density function of `Z=f(X,Y)`.

By looking at [this post](https://www.zhihu.com/question/37400689/answer/477717615), I know some types of probability density functions for Z=f(X,Y).

[image]

By using the M function, the probability density function of `Z=XY` is quickly obtained:

```
dist = TransformedDistribution[
   x y, {x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[], 
    y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]}];
PDF[dist][x]
Plot[PDF[dist][x], {x, -1, 1}, Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> Full]
```

But when I use the above method to find other probability density functions of type `Z=f(X,Y)` and `W=f[X,Y,Z]` , I have encountered difficulties, and MMA has been running without outputting results:

```
dist = TransformedDistribution[
   x^y, {x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[], 
    y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]}];
PDF[dist][x]
Plot[PDF[dist][x], {x, -1, 1}, Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> Full]


dist = TransformedDistribution[
  x*y*z, {x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[], 
   y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[], 
   z \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]}]
PDF[dist][w]
Plot[PDF[dist][w], {w, 0, 1}, Filling -> Axis]
```

What should I do to find and plot the probability density functions of other `Z=f(X,Y)` types ($Z=X^Y$,$Z=\sqrt[Y]{X}$,$Z=\log_{X}{Y}$,$W=XYZ$,...)?

Comment: What you're refering to is not an article, just a post in zhihu, and a quick test shows the first result is wrong: `test1[z_] := -1/(2 Pi)
    NIntegrate[Exp[-1/(2 x^2) - z^(2 x)/2] Abs[z^(x - 1)/x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}];


test2[z_] := -1/(2 Pi)
    NIntegrate[Exp[-x^2/2 - z^(2/x)/2] Abs[1/x z^(1/x - 1)/x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}];{test1[1], test2[1]}`

Comment: @xzczd Thank you very much, I will think about this question again.

Comment: @xzczd Agreed:  the first example is so wrong that it gives negative values for every value of $z$.  To the OP:  Are you expecting complex or imaginary values for $Z$?  If you're only interesting in real numbers, then $X^Y$ won't do it for you.  You'd need to consider $|X|^Y$.

Comment: @JimB Thanks, but when I use the following code MMA still keeps running and returns no results: `dist = TransformedDistribution[RealAbs[x]^y, {x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[], 
   y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]}]`.

Comment: I wasn't actually suggesting you do that.  (Maybe as a classroom exercise but likely no practical reason to have a real-world use for such a random variable.)  I was only pointing out that some transformations result in complex numbers.

Comment: @JimB The following code can't return the result. I want to know how MMA can calculate their probability distribution and graphics: `dist = TransformedDistribution[
    Log[x, y], {x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[], 
     y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]}] // N;

Plot[PDF[dist][x], {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> Axis]`

Comment: With that random variable `Log[x, y]` one gets complex numbers.  Is that what you want?

Comment: @JimB Thank you, please write about the process, I will learn some ideas.

Comment: You should take a look at https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RatioDistribution.html for a general method to obtain the distribution of the ratio of two random variables.